# Filling a Color Array with a Gradient

Tags: java, arrays, colors

I'm trying to generate with code a one dimensional array of Color in java with a gradient of color, how can I do this? I also want to be able to use multiple colors in the gradient.

I want it to be sort of like this: [image: Linear gradient]

Comment: Store Hexadecimal(RGB code) value of color in the array.

Comment: Let me edit my question.

Comment: do you mean that you want to store all RGB code from `#000000` to `#FFFFFF` into an array?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's break this down into some generic steps:

1. Figure out what the RGB values for `startColor` and `endColor` are. For example, perhaps they are `(64, 128, 192)` and `(255, 255, 255)`
2. Figure out how many steps in your color gradient you want. Based on your question, it looks like you want 100 steps.  You probably don't need 100, though it depends on what you want to do with it I suppose.
3. Figure out the difference between each color value - in my example, it's `(191, 127, 63)`.
4. Now you know how much to change each value for each loop iteration: `(191/100, 127/100, 63/100)`.
5. Create a loop that starts with your `startColor`, applies (rounded) change to the color values each iteration, adding each new `Color` to your array. At the end of your loop, the last `Color` added will end up being the `endColor`

Voila - there's your array of `Color` objects representing your gradient.

If you want, you should be able to figure out how to extend this to a multi-color gradient (red -> yellow -> green) as well, simply by creating two loops that transition to each color.